# Slack API can't base64 decode?

Tags: python, api, aws-lambda, base64, slack-api

I'm banging my head on my desk over this issue. I've got a Lambda function that is invoked by hitting an API Gateway. Here's an example of the code I'm trying to run.

```
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return base64.b64decode("aGVsbG8K")
```

When I test this within Lambda natively, it returns "hello", which is the correct base64 decoding. When I try run it in slack, I get the following message:

```
/cmd failed with the error "dispatch_failed"
```

I have verified that the bot has all the correct permissions and can message the channel as the following code works perfectly fine and sends "hello".

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "hello"
```

Any ideas? I've been on this for at least five hours and haven't gotten anywhere.

The main issue is that I'm trying to access and decode `event['body']` in my actual code as it is base64 encoded and I have no idea how to switch `"isBase64Encoded": true` to `false` within the Slack API/API Gateway.

Comment: "dispatch_failed" simply means Slack has not received the expected response and this could be for any reason that we cannot see. You will need to check the lambda logs in CloudWatch to see what error is being thrown or maybe update your code to return the response status and body that Slack requires.

Comment: How are you testing the Lambda "natively"?

Comment: I'm facing similar issues. The `event` is a dictionary. It seems the `body` is encoded, but the rest of the `event` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question here, you can accomplish this with the following:

```
from base64 import b64decode

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    slack_body = b64decode(event.get('body'))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f'Slack event body: {slack_body}')
    }
```

See my comment above for additional information.

I'm struggling with this because I can't seem to decode the `body`, but then get the `command` and command `text` from it.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/glasswall-engineering/how-to-create-a-slack-bot-using-aws-lambda-in-1-hour-1dbc1b6f021c) useful to an extent.